# Dying houseplant

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers

Could anyone help me identify this plant and tell me how should I take care of it?
Thank you in advance
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Calathea triostar - it likes high humidity, so it's good in kitchens or bathrooms, so long as there is a source of bright daylight without direct sun. A north facing windowsill approximates the right amount of light. They need to be kept well watered, though not soaking wet all the time, water when the surface of the soil is just slightly dry to the touch, water thoroughly and allow excess to drain away freely, not allowing water to remain in the outer pot - empty that after 30 minutes. They benefit from frequent misting with tepid water, do not appreciate draughts, nor temperatures below 15 deg C. Yours appears to be suffering from dry air, possibly (but less likely) underwatering, maybe some sun exposure, hard to say because it's not clear how much light it gets and whether it is exposed to sun. Image and info here https://www.waitrosegarden.com/plants/_/calathea-triostar/classid.2000031746/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwgMnYBRDRARIsANC2dfnIaRbm0hUfaB1BTPHWgMsWV88N6x_O1NUa4Enuudktt1MsqCRV_7IaAj-rEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CPORhPCFttsCFcKlUQodmNQLdw

These are not particularly easy houseplants because of their humidity and watering requirements, but it is possible to split a large plant by cutting it in half. If you do that, it needs nursing - each section should be potted up separately, and kept covered with a plastic bag, using sticks round the pot to keep the plastic off the leaves. Once you see new growth appearing, you can remove the plastic, but if you cannot provide the humidity they require, they won't do well ongoing.

Comment: Thank you so much. And how should I get rid of the dead leaves?

Comment: Cut them off as close to soil level as possible.