# Calathea advice needed

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors, plant-care, plant-recommendations

can anybody help me with some advice on how to revive this calathea? Since autumn [here in the UK] it hasn't been doing so well. It's in a fairly bright spot, an hour or so of fairly direct light. I have a humidify running for an hour a day too. I'm not sure if I am over watering or underwatering, I water it roughly when the top inch of soil is dry. Some a lot of the leaves come out brown and dry, some don't un-roll at all and all the stems are weak too, the can't support the weight of their own leaves, they droop, bend and eventually break. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39029/dying-houseplant check out the answer I got in this post. I think it can help you

Comment: Thanks. Did it work for your plant? Especially that amount of watering... when I bought it, I was told _not_ to water it too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my plant now so yes I think it worked [image]

Comment: Woooah, that’s an insane improvement in just half a year 